# plotting a two variable real valued function with domain given in vector format or discrete

Tags: plotting

I have a function $g(x,y)= -2x+5y$ and vector $ a=\{0,2,6,8,18,20,24,26\} $.

I want to plot a $ g(1,a) $ but i don't know how to plot it?

I use following commands:

```
g[x_,y_]:=-2 x+5 y; 
Plot[g[1,y],{y,a}]
```

But i does not get a plot.

Please help. Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: Try ListLinePlot@Table[1~g~y,{y,a}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = {0, 2, 6, 8, 18, 20, 24, 26};
g[x_, y_] := -2 x + 5 y
g[1, a]
```

> {-2, 8, 28, 38, 88, 98, 118, 128}

```
ListPlot[%]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `DiscretePlot`:

```
g[x_, y_] := -2 x + 5 y
DiscretePlot[g[1, y], {y, {0, 2, 6, 8, 18, 20, 24, 26}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Example

**Code**

```
a = {0, 2, 6, 8, 18, 20, 24, 26};
g[x_, y_] := -2 x + 5 y

ListPlot @ (g[1, #] & /@ a)
```

**Output**

[image: example]

**Reference**

[Map](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html)
[ListPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html)